# Document management using Plone4

Tags: wiki, plone, document-management, knowledge-management

I'm interested in making a document management system from Plone 4.

I need pointers to a way to integrate [FlexPaper](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/) and a way for asynchroneous document transformation using existing tools like SWFTools, Ghostscript, ImageMagick, Batik etc..

Thank you for any pointers you can give me.

Comment: you might be better off splitting your three requirements into three different questions

Comment: Thank you, but will I be creating duplicate entries? Can I just edit this question now and simply just leave one of these requirements? edit: decided that this is exactly what I'll do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Plone 4 is an excellent choice. We've been using it as a document management system internally and for a number of high profile clients. The main selling points are:

- Blobs are stored on the filesystem (not in the database);
- OpenOffice, MS Office, PDF documents are indexed and their content searchable;
- Fine grained ACLs;
- Workflows.

Regarding your points:

- http://plone.org/products/wc.pageturner for Flexpaper integration (we found that simply embedding the pdf, using Acrobat's plugin, worked fine too);
- Wiki style content editing is supported natively (via Wicked);
- Data lists can be implemented with a custom content-type, using DataGridField( http://plone.org/products/datagridfield ).

Other advantages:

- PloneFormGen, now with AJAX quick-edit ( http://plone.org/products/ploneformgen )
- Plomino, for TTW "Domino" style app creation ( http://www.plomino.net )
- WebDAV and XML-RPC;
- Content rules;
- User subscription to content and email notifications (see http://plone.org/products/cmfnotification );
- Can be installed as multi-headed, fully redundant system using ZEO and RelStorage (ZODB encapsulation in a RDBMS datastore backend, like MySQL, Postgres or Oracle),

Comment: Great information and very detailed answer! @Bojan Markovic, if you found this information OK, you should mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Oh ok, I just figured out how to actually do that. edit: I am also very impressed with how helpful, quick and dedicated the community is here.

Comment: Thanks. I raise a Sarajevska Pivo in your honor ;)

Comment: at the risk of going further off topic I'll say cheers and would gladly trade that beer with a glass of some lombardian Pinot Grigio being a vino bianco person myself ;)

Answer (score 2):

Plone has a built in document transformation system called plone.transforms http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.transforms.

There are plugins that use plone.transforms or just events to transform content, synchronously and asynchronously. For example take a look at http://plone.org/products/collective.pdfpeek

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Very useful information regarding the part of my question about document transfotmation.